# Type Mismatch error in Java generics

Tags: java, generics

```
public class SuperType<T> {

    T var;

    public T getVar(){
        return var;
    }
}

public class SubType extends SuperType<String>{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<SuperType<?>> ls = new ArrayList<SubType>();//(1) throwing an error
        List<?> ls1 = new ArrayList<String>();// no error
     }
}
```

I am trying to figure out why an error is being thrown at (1). Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, generics are invariant.  This means that even if `SubType` is a `SuperType<String>`, that doesn't mean that a `List<SubType>` is a `List<SuperType<?>>` or even a `List<SuperType<String>>`.  That is why (1) is an error.  You can resolve this by introducing a wildcard:

```
List<? extends SuperType<?>> ls = new ArrayList<SubType>();
```

The second line isn't an error, because the wildcard `?` means any type.

Note that using wildcards restricts what can be done with such lists, such as when you call `add`.